# explain $df(tx).x = \sum_{i=1}^n {\partial f\over \partial x_i}(tx)x_i \hspace{1cm} x\in \mathbb R^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

the question is :

let $U$ be a Neighbourhood of the origine of $R^n$ and :

$x\in U \Rightarrow tx \in U , \forall t\in U $

let f be a numeric function defined in U , and $f(0)= 0$

if we have $f\in C^1$ , prove the existence of $n$ numeric functions $f_i$ defined in U / 
$f_i(0)= {\partial f\over \partial x_i}(0) \, \, \forall i$ and :

$$ f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x) x_i  \hspace{1cm} \forall x=(x_1,x_2,....,x_n)\in U $$

and the answer is :

let $x\in U$ , the function $\phi : [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ , $t \to f(xt)$ . we have $\phi\in C^1$ with : 
$\phi(0)=0 \hspace{1cm} \phi(1)=f(x) , \phi'(t)= df(tx).x $

and then :

$df(tx).x = \sum_{i=1}^n {\partial f\over \partial x_i}(tx)x_i $  , i dont understand this !, first of all , x is a vector and $\phi'(t)$ is not ! (cuz i saw that $\phi'(t)=df.vector$ wich make it a vector) , and how they came up with $=\sum_{i=1}^n {\partial f\over \partial x_i}(tx)x_i$ next ?

the rest of the solution is :

$f(x)=\int_0^1\phi(t)dt = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x).x_i \Rightarrow f_i(x)=\int_0^1 {\partial f\over \partial x_i}(tx)dt $

im having this type of problem everywhere , can someone explain to me what should happen to the vector when we took it outside after we devided  ?

Comment: meta: you can use horizontal space "\hspace{1cm}" instead of chains of backslash, see [doku](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/spacebox.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just chain rule, $ \phi(t) = f(tx) $ implies $$ \phi'(t) = \nabla f(tx).x = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(tx)x_i $$
You have gradient defined as $$ \nabla f = \Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},....,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\Bigr) $$
and for any curve $\gamma $ chain rule gives you that $ (f\circ \gamma)'(t) = \nabla f(\gamma(t)).\gamma'(t) $. In this case $ \gamma(t) = tx $.